# Accidentally baked oxygen absorber between two naan, is everything fine?

Tags: food-safety, oven

I didn't notice it because it was between two pieces of naan instead of easily seen within the packet itself. I baked it in foil at 200°C (392 °F) with the fan on. It wasn't melted and didn't look burnt or anything but it was hot to the touch. I'm a pretty health concerned person so I'd appreciate anyone else's experiences.

I wasn't able to upload images directly so I uploaded them on imgur instead:

https://imgur.io/a/dD9tj8Q